# If a convex set is "non-trivial in every direction" then it contains the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open convex set. Suppose that, for any direction $\nu$ (i.e. every unit vector $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^n$) there exists $x_\nu\in U$ such that
$$
\nu\cdot x_\nu > 0.
$$
Then, can I conclude that the origin is contained in $U$ or, at least, in the closure of $U$?

I came up with this problem while reading and it feels true but I can't prove it. Any ideas? If this is somewhat well-known and there is a source it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick partial answer, certainly the origin must be in the closure of your set. In fact, somethign slightly stronger than this is true, namely we do not need our set to have nonempty interior. If $S$ is a closed convex set not containing the origin which satisfies your dot product condition, let $v$ be the element of $S$ closest to the origin (which exists since $S$ is closed) and consider any element $w$ of $S$ which has positive dot product with the direction **opposite** $v$. By convexity the entire line segment $\overline{vw}$ is contained in $S$, but this line segment contains points that are strictly closer to the origin than $v$ is, contradicting our assumption.

Comment: This is essentially a complete answer. If the closest point to the closure of $U$ is not in $U$ then the inner product of $U$ in opposite direction (or rather the direction of the separating hyperplane) must be $\le 0$ which contradicts the inner product condition.

Comment: And since the OP asked for a reference, this is the special case of the hyperplane separation theorem where one set is a point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem

Answer (score 5):

If the origin is not in the set, by the hyperplane characterization of convexity there exists a direction $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and hyperplane  $$H_\nu:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x\cdot \nu=0\}$$ containing $0$ and having $U$ lie on one side, I.e. $U\subset\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x\cdot \nu\geq0\}$. From the previous containment, one see $-\nu\notin U$.

Answer (score 2):

For a compact non empty convex set $C$, define the support function as $\sigma_C(h) = \max_{c \in C} \langle h, c \rangle$ (Rockafellar's notation is $\delta^*(h | C)$). It is straighforward to show that, for two compact non empty convex sets $C_1,C_2$ that $C_1 \subset C_2$ **iff** $\sigma_{C_1} (h) \le  \sigma_{C_2} (h)$ for all $h$. It is also straightforward to show that $\sigma_C$ is continuous.

Choose $R>0$ such that $C = \overline{B}(0,R) \cap \overline{U}$ is non empty. In particular, $C$ is convex, non empty and compact. Furthermore, $\sigma_C(h) >0$ for all $h$, and hence $r=\min_{\|h\|=1} \sigma_C(h) >0$. Consequently,
$\sigma_{\overline{B}(0,r)} (h) \le \sigma_C(h)$ for all $h$ and
so $\overline{B}(0,r) \subset \overline{B}(0,R) \cap \overline{U} \subset \overline{U}$. Hence
$B(0,r) = \overline{B}(0,r)^\circ \subset \overline{U}^\circ = U$
(since both sets are open & convex).